# Can't telnet 9100 on 2 windows servers on same network

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, telnet

I have 2 servers A and B on same subnet. Both can't telnet each other on 9100

Connecting To (Server IP) ...Could not open connection to the host, on port 9100: Connect failed

1. Both are 2012 R2
2. Both can ping each other. And telnet is working on other opened
   ports like 135 . Issue is only with 9100 port.
3. Firewall is disabled already on all network types -I've created
   inbound and outbound rules to allow TCP 9100 on both. But then found
   that Firewall is disabled so rules are useless.
4. I have disabled trend micro AV on both servers but still issue
   remains
5. Server A is a printing server.. so it communicates with different
   printers in different sites on port 9100.

On Server A > `netstat -an | findstr 9100` gives output like :

[image: Image Output of netstat on Server A]

6. Server B is a back up for A. It got a couple of printers but not
   really used.

On Server B > `netstat -an | findstr 9100` gives No output

I'm kinda stuck and can't provide any solution.

Comment: Please provide the output of `netstat -an`

Comment: Are you sure something is listening on port 9100?

Comment: @mashuptwice thanks for helping me.  I have updated post with netstat -an  | findstr output

Comment: @StarCat thanks for helping. I have updated post with netstat -an | findstr 9100 on both servers

Comment: What originally made you think that you _should_ be able to connect to servers on this port?

Comment: @user1686 Actually my logic was that if FW is disabled on all networks then I should be able to connect on this port. I've been asked by upper management to make sure this port is open between 2 servers . And I'm new in the company and the environment + I'm a junior admin so not much knowledge :)

Comment: @Recon: Ah, that's not how "open ports" work at all...

Comment: @user1686 Can you please clarify a bit more ? i'm doing my research in parallel

Comment: @Recon Just because a port is not blocked by the firewall, doesn't mean that something magically will answer when connecting to to the port (e.g. via telnet). In any case you need some sort of software to handle the request to the port.